# Change current revision of existing repo in Mercurial

Tags: debugging, mercurial

I'm tracking a complex bug and I want to find out the changeset that introduced it by testing the program with old revisions.

Given a local mercurial repository with 100 changesets, how can I pull(revert ? clone ?) to a previous (ex.50) changeset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have any work to lose then you can say:

```
hg update -c -r REV
```

That says update to revision REV (a number), and discard any uncommitted changes I have.

Also, hg already has command especially for trying to find a change that something was broken.

```
hg bisect
```

There is a [chapter about it here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/finding-and-fixing-mistakes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand you, you can use `hg update REV` to update the working copy to the specified revision.

Comment: This seems to be a possible solution, so can I do something like `hg update -r 50` and then `hg update -r tip` to get back to tip ?

Comment: Yes. Things may get a bit more complicated if you make changes in the working copy.